# Having different output item numbers on different ports gnuradio

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have a block which has two output ports in gnuradio. I need to return a single items to one output port and some specific n output items on another output port. Is this possible or always it returns same number of items on different ports

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. `gr::block` has a method called `produce(int,int)` to allow you to do exactly that. You'll have to `return WORK_CALLED_PRODUCE` instead of returning a  number of samples.

Of course, not producing the same amount on all outputs means that you can't use `sync_block` and quite likely will have to implement a `forecast()` too.